# How to UIButton state in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

Is there anyway to control `UIButton` state (*enable/disable button*) in `UITableViewCell`. My problem is my `UIButton` in cell is made in `storyboard` using `viewWithTag`. I've been spending quite a lot of time to sort it out but no luck. People mostly sort out the problem by programmatically assigning the tag for the button with cell `indexPath`.

I'm aware of that the table will reuse the cell, but I just want to ask if there is another hacky way to sort out my issue. If it is impossible, I might have to create the button programmatically.

Comment: what do you mean with "state"?

Comment: I want to disable the button when I click on. But the problem is the cell is reuse, so when I scroll down the table view, the button from other cell wil be unable to click as well.

Comment: you have a  custom cell?

Comment: @MirkoCatalano I design the cell on `storyboard` but don't have a dedicated class for the cell. in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I use the button with `UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100]`. and have a method to `-setEnable:` when button is clicked.

Comment: this is wrong if you make a custom cell everything will be easy and can manage your problem with the method prepareToReuse

Comment: have you tried my custom cell?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the subviews of the cell and check if they are a UIButton using `isMemberOfClass` to get your button. If you have multiple buttons you could then check the text of the button or some other property that uniquely identifies it. That would be a hacky way to do it.

Comment: I also tried your solution before, but it doesn't work. when I click on the button, the button on that row is disabled, but when scrolling down, the cell is reused, some buttons in other rows get disabled as well :(. It's because my button tag is not set corressponding to `indexPath`. As I mentioned, I just created a button by using `storyboard` and use it by `-viewWithTag:`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom cell like that:

**CustomCell.h**

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;


@end
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)prepareForReuse{
    self.button.enable = YES;
}


- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
[self.delegate buttonPressed:sender];
}
@end
```

after in IB you add a new UITableViewCell at your UITableView and the class of it with you new custom cell set the Identify ID like "CustomCell" add your Button to your custom cell and connect the Outlet, then you modify you tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: like that:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CustomCell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 cell.delegate = self;

return cell;
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
sender.enable = NO;
}
```

Also you have to add the CustomCellDelegate in your controller's heater file

Comment: Tks mate for your detail solution, I tried it but not work. Whenever the cell is reused, the button state is reset

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to keep a NSMutableArray variable in your viewcontroller and with that keep track of what cells button is disabled/enabled. And use the UITableViewDataDelegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to set the buttons state each time it gets displayed. And UITableViewDelegate method:

```
– tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)tableViewCell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to write to the array. Indexing with indexPath.